# Google maps AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to make GoogleMap application. But when I start it I have an exception. Here's my code and LogCat output. When I start the application there's an exclamation point in the "Target" column. Thanks a lot!!!

Here's my main class:

```
    package com.example.googlem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Notification.Style;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection;
import com.google.android.maps.*;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager locman;
    LocationListener loclis;
    Location Location;
    private MapView map;

    List<GeoPoint> geoPointsArray = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    private MapController controller;
    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    double lat;
    double lon;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initMapView();
        initMyLocation();
        locman = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // locman.requestLocationUpdates(provider,60000, 100,loclis);
        // Location = locman.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    }

    /** Find and initialize the map view. */
    private void initMapView() {

        //map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            //.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
         map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        controller = map.getController();
        map.setSatellite(false);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    /** Find Current Position on Map. */
    private void initMyLocation() {
        final MyLocationOverlay overlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);
        overlay.enableMyLocation();
        overlay.enableCompass(); 
        overlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Zoom in to current location
                controller.setZoom(24);
                controller.animateTo(overlay.getMyLocation());
            }
        });
        map.getOverlays().add(overlay);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (Location != null) {
            lat = Location.getLatitude();
            lon = Location.getLongitude();
            GeoPoint New_geopoint = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1e6),
                    (int) (lon * 1e6));
            controller.animateTo(New_geopoint);

        }

    }

    class MyOverlay extends Overlay {
        public MyOverlay() {
        }

        public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);

            com.google.android.maps.Projection projection = map.getProjection();
            Path p = new Path();
            for (int i = 0; i < geoPointsArray.size(); i++) {
                if (i == geoPointsArray.size() - 1) {
                    break;
                }
                Point from = new Point();
                Point to = new Point();
                projection.toPixels(geoPointsArray.get(i), from);
                projection.toPixels(geoPointsArray.get(i + 1), to);
                p.moveTo(from.x, from.y);
                p.lineTo(to.x, to.y);
            }
            Paint mPaint = new Paint();
            // mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
            super.draw(canvas, map, shadow);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >   

     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="403dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

My manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlem"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

     <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

    <permission android:name="com.example.googlem.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlem.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCQ9zcNrIq6ooXc5GeACEFdaHARxB9GnVU"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlem.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat output:

```
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlem/com.example.googlem.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2463)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:342)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at com.example.googlem.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:87)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5165)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1103)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     ... 11 more
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
11-30 09:14:47.323: E/AndroidRuntime(5297):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: add this  `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` in application tag of manifest

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: You need to specify a version for Google Play Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your exception saying that:

You must have the following declaration within application tag of manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```